# Объявление объектов JavaScript инлайн

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

```js
function Note(src,parent,childs) {
    this.curi = 0;
    this.src = "../img/7000i/menu/"+src+".bmp";
    this.parent = parent;
    this.childs = [];

    this.addChilds = function(childs) {
      for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        this.childs.push(childs[i]);
      } 
    }

    this.curChild = function() {
      return this.childs[this.curi];
    }

    this.nextChild = function() {
      if (this.curi < this.childs.length) {
        this.curi++;
        return this.childs[this.curi];
      } 
    }

    this.prevChild = function() {
      if (this.curi >= this.childs.length) {
        this.curi--;
        return this.childs[this.curi];
      } 
    }
}

var Main_menu = new Note();
Main_menu.addChilds([
    new Note(1),
    new Note(2),
    new Note(3),  
    new Note(4),      
    new Note(5),    
    new Note(6),    
    new Note(null)  
]);

console.dir(Main_menu.childs);
```

Если вызвать в конструкторе `new Note(1).addChilds([1,2,3,4])`, то на выходе это элемент `undefined`.
Как можно все в инлайн инициализировать?

```js
var Main_menu = new Note();
Main_menu.addChilds([
    new Note(1).addChilds([1,2,3,4]),
    new Note(2),
    new Note(3),    
    new Note(4),      
    new Note(5),   
    new Note(6),   
    new Note(null)  
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так `new Note(1).addChilds([1,2,3,4])` вызываете `addChilds` не в конструкторе. Так вы вызываете `addChilds` на только что созданном экземпляре. А сам `addChilds` ничего не возвращает, поэтому и получается `undefined`.

В вашем `addChilds` верните `this`. Вот так:

```
this.addChilds = function(childs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        this.childs.push(childs[i]);
    }   
    return this;
}
```

Тогда и такой вызов будет работать:

```
var mainMenu = new Note();
mainMenu.addChilds([
    new Note(1).addChilds([1,2,3,4]),
    new Note(2),
    new Note(3),    
    new Note(4),      
    new Note(5),   
    new Note(6),   
    new Note(null)  
]);
```

Либо в самом конструкторе используйте объявленный аргумент `childs`:

```
// Вместо
this.childs = [];

// Напишите это
this.childs = childs || [];

// Что по сути равно этому:
if (childs != undefined) this.childs = childs;
else this.childs = [];
```

А ваш "inline" вызов запишите так:

```
var mainMenu = new Note();
mainMenu.addChilds([
    new Note(1, undefined, [1,2,3,4]),
    new Note(2),
    new Note(3),    
    new Note(4),      
    new Note(5),   
    new Note(6),   
    new Note(null)  
]);
```

А еще вы неправильно строите свой объект в конструкторе. Точнее не то, чтобы совсем неправильно, просто на каждый объект у вас будет собственная копия каждой функции. И могут быть большие затраты памяти. Лучше объявить функции не в конструкторе, а через `prototype`:

```
function YourContructor(arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
    ....
}

YourConstructor.prototype.someFunction = function(fArg1, fArg2) {
    // какая-то логика
}
```

И тогда все объекты будут использовать одну у ту же функцию.